# Firefox WebDriver/GeckoDriver/Marionette ElementClick slow

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, firefox-marionette

The following script takes more than 20 seconds on my machine:

```
import selenium.webdriver
import tempfile

def run_webdriver(url):
    with selenium.webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
        driver.get(url)
        button = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
        for i in range(100):
            button.click()

def main():
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.html') as f:
        f.write(b'<!DOCTYPE html><title>x</title><button>x</button>')
        f.flush()
        run_webdriver('file://' + f.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) shows that the bottleneck is in `click` and waiting for GeckoDriver.

```
      100    0.001    0.000   22.101    0.221 webelement.py:78(click)
      105   24.073    0.229   24.073    0.229 {method 'recv_into' of '_socket.socket' objects}
```

[GeckoDriver log](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/TraceLogs.html) shows that it takes Marionette 200ms to execute each `WebDriver:ElementClick`:

```
$ awk '/Marionette.*->/{ start = $1; request = $6; } /Marionette.*<-/{ print($1 - start, request, $6);  }' geckodriver.log | head
15 [0,1,"WebDriver:NewSession",{"acceptInsecureCerts":true,"browserName":"firefox"}] [1,1,null,{"sessionId":"ef9259e3-8f12-4cc2-a6e1-66846e7b4b77","capabilities":{"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"93.0"
248 [0,2,"WebDriver:Navigate",{"url":"file:///tmp/tmp_o5arvre.html"}] [1,2,null,{"value":null}]
10 [0,3,"WebDriver:FindElement",{"using":"css [1,3,null,{"value":{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"73ed82bf-391a-4e62-98b3-7a6a260e3843"}}]
214 [0,4,"WebDriver:ElementClick",{"id":"73ed82bf-391a-4e62-98b3-7a6a260e3843"}] [1,4,null,{"value":null}]
207 [0,5,"WebDriver:ElementClick",{"id":"73ed82bf-391a-4e62-98b3-7a6a260e3843"}] [1,5,null,{"value":null}]
208 [0,6,"WebDriver:ElementClick",{"id":"73ed82bf-391a-4e62-98b3-7a6a260e3843"}] [1,6,null,{"value":null}]
207 [0,7,"WebDriver:ElementClick",{"id":"73ed82bf-391a-4e62-98b3-7a6a260e3843"}] [1,7,null,{"value":null}]
213 [0,8,"WebDriver:ElementClick",{"id":"73ed82bf-391a-4e62-98b3-7a6a260e3843"}] [1,8,null,{"value":null}]
207 [0,9,"WebDriver:ElementClick",{"id":"73ed82bf-391a-4e62-98b3-7a6a260e3843"}] [1,9,null,{"value":null}]
208 [0,10,"WebDriver:ElementClick",{"id":"73ed82bf-391a-4e62-98b3-7a6a260e3843"}] [1,10,null,{"value":null}]
```

Why does ElementClick take 200ms? Can it be sped up?

Environment:

- Arch Linux
- sway 1:1.6.1-1
- firefox 93.0-1
- geckodriver 0.30.0-1
- python-selenium 3.141.0-3
- python 3.9.7-1

Answer (score 0):

ElementClick should wait for navigation to complete<sup>[1](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-click)</sup>. Unfortunately, that's implemented in Marionette by waiting for 200ms to check for beforeunload event<sup>[2](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/5e7976773895d72e47a76a9c912fbf3d0171e610/remote/marionette/navigate.js#30)</sup>.

A workaround is to add `target=_blank` attribute to the button<sup>[3](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/5e7976773895d72e47a76a9c912fbf3d0171e610/remote/marionette/driver.js#1478),[4](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/5e7976773895d72e47a76a9c912fbf3d0171e610/remote/marionette/navigate.js#113)</sup>, even though it's not an `<a>`. For example:

```py
def run_webdriver(url):
    with selenium.webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
        driver.get(url)
        driver.execute_script('''
          document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(
            (element) => element.setAttribute('target', '_blank'));
        ''')
        button = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
        for i in range(100):
            button.click()
```

The script now takes only 5 seconds.